# Watermark suggestions for portfolio work

Tags: images, copyright, portfolio, marketing

I’m open to either mobile or desktop applications, I’d like to start water marking my work and making illustrated marketing photos for advertisements.

I've tried a bunch of free apps but I’d like one that can possibly bulk mark or  auto save the mark at the size and selection to place the following watermark/copyright.

Comment: Both Photoshop and Lightroom Classic have a watermarking feature for text and/or images which can be set up as a Preset and used over and over. Both can also set up batch or bulk operations to apply to many images at a time. Typically each image will need placement, color, opacity, etc. tweaked a bit to work best on each different photo.

Comment: These are windows ex’s applications correct? You mentioned classic makes me think they might be free? 

Either way nice start thank you Kyle.

Comment: Both applications are Adobe applications  and they are not free- Yes, they work for both Mac and Windows OS- Lightroom "Classic" refers to their desktop app (which is more robust than the mobile version)- I am not sure if the mobile version is free or not...

Answer (score 0):

The list is too long to make a partial list of applications to consider

- Photoshop
- Lightroom (both versions)
- Imagemagick (free, imagemagic is the workhorse for any batch processing works everywhere even my tv can run it)

But realistically nearly any image software can do this. Some better some worse. From top of my head i came up with atleast 20 ways i could do it without installing anything on my computers.

Comment: I mean I can too it’s just I want some professional and unique I’m not gonna creat just anything I want something my clients and future clients recognize lol sorry for the dumb question guys geez.

Comment: @JohnnyT first thing to learn if your doing visual communication design is that you need to repeat the substance of a title in the body text or you can and will get misunderstood